# Did the word "responsibility" come from the two words "response ability"

Tags: etymology

For example, if you had better response ability you would receive more difficult tasks.  And if you are responsible you are response able, or able to respond.

Answer (score 2):

No, it did not.

Etymologically, the word "responsibility" comes from an obsolete French word "responsible", itself coming from a Latin word "responsabilis", the past participle of "respondere", meaning "to respond". The word did not come to imply any measure of accountability until the middle 1600s.

[Etymonline / Responsibility](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=responsibility&allowed_in_frame=0)

The suffix "-ability", on the other hand, comes from the Latin use of "-abilitas" onto an adjective to form a noun.

[Etymonline / -ability](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ability&allowed_in_frame=0)

The word *ability*, though, is surprisingly not derived from this use of the "-abilitas" suffix in Latin. It comes from the Old French "ableté", meaning literally "ability" or "capability".

[Etymonline / Ability](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=ability&allowed_in_frame=0)

Comment: So I was sort of on the right track. :) I just didn't go back far enough.

Comment: When researching etymology, it's useful to keep in mind that suffixes and prefixes aren't always etymologically linked to similar (sometimes even identical) words. You should always check prefixes and suffixes independently of the root for this reason. :)

Comment: As  Dan Bron has said here, 'Answering off-topic questions on the ... site sends the wrong message to the user-base.' This question is general reference.

Comment: Apologies, it did not occur to me that this might be off topic. Is there a list of in-scope question types available for reference?

Comment: The main explanation of on-topic/off-topic is this Help Center page:  [What topics can I ask about here?](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Edwin Ashworth and I voted to close this question as off-topic using the following close reason: "Please include the [research](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/5039) you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573) are off-topic."

Comment: In this case, it seems like a dictionary entry for "responsibility" would explain the original poster's question. It's not a big deal to answer a question like this since you didn't know, but it is discouraged because answering a question makes it stick around longer: a question with upvoted answers cannot be [automatically deleted](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/roomba). Closed questions are generally supposed to be deleted if they are not improved, so answering off-topic questions before they are closed makes more work for people (the questions will have to be manually deleted).

Comment: Got it, thank you for the links. I will keep that in mind. A dictionary entry would not answer this question by itself because dictionary etymologies tend to not be so specific or elaborate, but I see etymonline.com is listed as a resource. Cheers, I'll defer to commenting on similar questions with a link to the Resources page in the future.